# How can I use my own data in this custom R visual?

Tags: r, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to create a custom visual in Power BI based on an R script much like in the example found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/RVisualTutorial/CreateRHTML.md). Once I have it running in Power BI, how can I edit the script (shown below) to allow Power BI to use my own data rather than the data in the library?

```
source('./r_files/flatten_HTML.r')

############### Library Declarations ###############
libraryRequireInstall("ggplot2");
libraryRequireInstall("plotly")
####################################################

################### Actual code ####################
g = qplot(`Petal.Length`, data = iris, fill = `Species`, main = Sys.time());
####################################################

############# Create and save widget ###############
p = ggplotly(g);
internalSaveWidget(p, 'out.html');
####################################################
```

When I attempt to change "iris" to dataset, it can't find dataset. I've also tried adding dataset <- data.frame(MyColumns) to no avail.

Comment: Shooting from the hip here but have you tried `read.table(text="yourdata.frame")`. I use that to import data from text files or websites sometimes.

Comment: Do you know the basics of how to read a data file into R? If not I suggest you read some tutorials. You are not going to be able to make meaningful changes to this script without learning some of the basics of how R works.

Comment: Type `?read.table` into the console...

Answer (score 1):

You can change like

imported table in power BI - Table1  ,Table2

g = qplot(`Table1.Coloumn_name`', data = iris, fill =`Species`, main = Sys.time());

Answer (score 0):

When you activate an `R visual`, you're prompted to `Drag fields into the Values area in the Visualization pane to start scripting`:

[image]

If you start with a simple dataset such as this:

```
A,B
1,11
2,19
3,18
4,19
5,18
6,12
7,12
8,19
9,13
10,19
```

...you can drag both columns into the visual, and access the data as a dataframe just the way the R Script Editor prompts you to:

[image]

So with the provided data sample, and stripped down equivalent to your data snippet such as this:

```
library(ggplot2)
g = qplot(`A`, data = dataset)
g
```

... you should be good to go!

[image]

Comment: @aGuy Was this not what you were looking for?